# recordForm error Handling

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-record-form

I have a recordForm like this:-

```
    <aura:attribute name="KeyDealInfoSectionfieldlist" type="String[]" default="field1__c,field2__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String" default="Opportunity"/>
    <lightning:messages aura:id="emessages"/>

    <lightning:recordForm aura:id="recordViewForm" 
        objectApiName="{!v.objectName}"
        columns="1"
        fields="{!v.KeyDealInfoSectionfieldlist}"
        recordId="{!v.currentid}"
        mode="view"
        onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}"
        onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}"
        onload="{!c.onLoad}"
        onerror="{!c.onError}"/>
```

I have some Validation rule on fields used in the above form. When validation becomes true, error message appears on the page but their is no way to remove the message till we refresh the whole page.

[image]

What I am doing wrong here?